# Encode the client viewable source in HTML

Tags: html

How to encode our HTML coding, so that they are not easily readable.

Answer (score 1):

This is called obfuscation and there are several tools to perform it.  [Here](http://www.voormedia.com/en/tools/html-obfuscate-scrambler.php) is one.  The process can of course be reversed.

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=obfuscate+html&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-GB:unofficial&client=firefox-a